# bazel install io_bazel_stardoc//stardoc in bazel 3.7.2

Tags: bazel

I am using bazel 3.7.2.

I am getting this error

error loading package '@maven//': Unable to find package for @io_bazel_stardoc//stardoc:stardoc.bzl: The repository '@io_bazel_stardoc' could not be resolved.

This is my workspace

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.3/bazel-skylib-1.0.3.tar.gz",
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.3/bazel-skylib-1.0.3.tar.gz",
    ],
    sha256 = "1c531376ac7e5a180e0237938a2536de0c54d93f5c278634818e0efc952dd56c",
)
load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")
bazel_skylib_workspace()

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "4.0"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "31701ad93dbfe544d597dbe62c9a1fdd76d81d8a9150c2bf1ecf928ecdf97169"

http_archive(
    name = "maven",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

load("@maven//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")


maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1",
        "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11"
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
git_repository(
    name = "io_bazel_stardoc",
    remote = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/stardoc.git",
    tag = "0.4.0",
)

load("@io_bazel_stardoc//:setup.bzl", "stardoc_repositories")
stardoc_repositories()
```